enumerateModules with Frida Python
I use Frida with Python.
Connect to remote process
import frida


frida.get_device_manager().add_remote_device('192.168.3.55:2222').attach(1234)

How can I enumerate modules  like I did in Frida cli(Javascript)
Process.enumerateModules();

But with Python?

The process is the same as when using frida command, the Python code can only be used on client side. For server side you have to load Frida JavaScript code.
You can do this by integrating a JavaScript file as String into your Python code:
Frida Python Script with integrated JavaScript source
import frida, sys
 
script = """
    Process.enumerateModules({
        onMatch: function(module){
            console.log('Module name: ' + module.name + " - " + "Base Address: " + module.base.toString());
        }, 
        onComplete: function(){}
    });
"""
session = frida.get_device_manager().add_remote_device('192.168.3.55:2222').attach(1234)
script = session.create_script(script)
script.load()
sys.stdin.read()

Or the way I prefer, having a separate JavaScript file that is loaded in the Python code:
Frida Python Script and external JavaScript source file
script.js
rpc.exports = {
    modules: function() {
        return Process.enumerateModules();
    }
}

my-frida.py
import frida, sys
import codecs

frida_js = './script.js'
with codecs.open(frida_js, 'r', 'utf-8') as f:
    source = f.read()

session = frida.get_device_manager().add_remote_device('192.168.3.55:2222').attach(1234)
script = session.create_script(source)
script.load()
modules = script.exports_sync.modules() # execute rpc exported modules function in loaded script
for m in modules:
    print(f'name={m["name"]} base={m["base"]} size={m["size"]} path={m["path"]}')

sys.stdin.read()


That you so much , that isn't the first time I saw from you Frida comment.  I learn from you. (Do you a a blog/articles?)

There is some commands you can run only with Python without JS  like frida.get_device_manager().add_remote_device('192.168.3.55:2222').enumerate_processes()  so I  thought if there is an option like that to get all the modules without using stdin or use send function to interact

@Polo1990 Please see my updated answer (2nd part with external JavaScript source file)  which uses rpc to call the function modules in the frida script and gets the returned data as list[dict]. Is this what you want to do?

That great thank you.

In frida 16.0.0 there is no exports_sync only exports @Robert
